# Как восстановить все файлы после примененной команды: git clean -f -q?

Tags: git

Решил попробовать встроенную функцию git'a в редакторе Visual Studio Code, нажал на кнопку на левой панели и началась синхронизация или что-то вроде этого. После того как все закончилось, куда-то подевались все файлы(((, остались только папки. Просмотрев все в терминале, обнаружил что для всех файлов была применена команда `git clean -f -q`.

Как восстановить обратно все файлы?

Comment: А все эти файлы хотя бы были добавлены с помощью `git add`?

Comment: Может быть, из временных файлов самой среды разработки можно восстановить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Нет. Я просто нажал на эту ***** кнопку и файлы исчезли. Теперь файлы видны только в самом редакторе

Comment: Как это видны в редакторе? Открыты во вкладках? Тогда скорее сохраняйте там.

Comment: @NickVolynkin  У меня все файлы синхронизированы в облачном хранилище **MEGASYNC**, только вот располагаются всей кучей в одной папке

Comment: @NickVolynkin Они видны в панели этого ***** git'a

Comment: гит не **** и панели у него никакой нет. Это VS Code ваши файлы потерла.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Так какие действия проделала команда **git clean -f -q**?

Comment: Описал подробно в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Что произошло

Команда `git clean` удаляет все файлы, которые не под контролем версий (т.е. ни разу не коммитились раньше в репозиторий git, untracked) и не игнорируются.

Обычно `git clean` используется для того, чтобы очистить проект от результатов сборки — логи, прекомпилированный код, всё что угодно ещё. Нередко бывает, что компилятор складывает эти файлы прямо рядом с кодом и сильно захламляет проект. Чистить такое руками тяжело — поэтому была придумана команда `git clean`.

Эта команда предполагает, что все нужные файлы уже под контролем версий. Она никогда не удалит уже закоммиченный файл. Похоже, что у вас в проекте репозиторий был только что инициализирован, поэтому команда `git clean` смогла удалить все файлы.

Почему и зачем `git clean -fq` была вызвана на каждом файле? Неизвестно. Так повелел больной разум разработчика из Microsoft, прикрутившего такой код к кнопке, которую вы нажали.

В будущем рекомендую вам не использовать графические клиенты для git, а пользоваться консолью. Опасную кнопку можно и случайно нажать, а вот шанс случайно набрать `git clean -fq path/filename` для каждого файла приблизительно нулевой.

#### Подробнее про `git clean -fq`

`man git-clean`:

> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory.
>
> Normally, only files unknown to Git are removed, but if the -x option is specified, ignored files are also removed. This can, for
>      example, be useful to remove all build products.

`-f` нужен для того, чтобы `git clean` действительно что-то удалил. Это страховка. Просто `git clean filename` не удалит файлы, только если вы заранее не сконфигурируете git в режим `я люблю рисковать`.

> `-f`, `--force`
>          If the Git configuration variable `clean.requireForce` is not set to false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories
>          unless given `-f`, `-n` or `-i`. Git will refuse to delete directories with `.git` sub directory or file unless a second `-f` is given.

С `-q` git удаляет файлы молча и без вопросов.

> `-q`, `--quiet`
>          Be quiet, only report errors, but not the files that are successfully removed.

Comment: Спасибо =) Можно вопрос?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин конечно.

Comment: Мой основной аккаунт был заблокирован за не очень качественные вопросы(, теперь мне запрещено задавать вопросы!  В описания "как снять блок" мне НЕ понятно что нужно сделать. Что-то типа "Делайте добрые дела для сайта", Какие? Может есть более понятное описание как снять блокировку?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин вроде была инструкция на Мете.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин держите: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5150/181472